# How to change abbreviated numbers into plain numbers in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm having a bit of an issue analyzing data in Google sheets. One of the columns has abbreviated numbers with K (thousand), and M (million). 
The abbreviation also doesn't seem to be consistent. Here's an example of a few rows:

```
185K 
3.06K 
4.19K 
59.2K 
1.38M 
64K 
2.78K 
6.21K 
4.5K
41.7K 
516K 
85.1K 
21.8K 
516K 
235K
```

Is there an easy way for me to convert these into plain numbers, for example, 41.7K -> 41700 ?

Appreciate the help!
Cheers

Comment: How is it "not consistent", I see no inconsistency in your sample. And are you sure the values are actually stored that way and not just displayed as such (i.e. what happens when you edit a field)?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I can't say with certainty that they're inconsistent. The examples that I added here do seem consistent. So the data is stored and displayed as you see above. That's because these are the numbers that were scraped using ScreamingFrog.

Comment: If there aren't too many of these numbers and you don't need to do this very often, it'd probably be easiest to copy the column into a text file and write an offline script to convert them, then paste them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What better place to write a script to convert these strings to values than a spreadsheet.

Try

`=if((right(A1,1))="K",(value(left(A1,(len(A1))-1)))*1000,if((right(A1,1))="M",(value(left(A1,(len(A1))-1)))*1000000,""))`